# Using React Router to hit Go backend

Tags: reactjs, go

I am having trouble trying to do a database insert. I have React front-end and I am trying to make a POST that hits my Go back-end. The react successfully makes a post 200, but it never actually hits the Go side of things. Any ideas on what I can do to successfully hit it?

In React I have:

```
postNewService = (newService) => {
    axios.post('api/add-ird/add', {newService} )
}
```

Which hits my addIRD.js form

```
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {

    const irdObj = {
        datacenterValue: req.body.newService.dataCenter,
        irdManagementIPValue: req.body.newService.irdManagementIP,

    }

    res.json(irdObj)
})

module.exports = router
```

and then I am trying to hit my Golang code here:

```
func startServer(port string, services Services, stop chan os.Signal) *http.Server {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/api/add-ird/add", services.createIRD).Methods("POST")

    srv := &http.Server{Addr: fmt.Sprintf(":%v", port), Handler: router}

    return srv
}
```

The problem is, it never successfully hits that route in my Go code because my function createIRD is never called. Do I need to modify my React axios post to successfully hit it?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not sending to /add? Your JS is really confusing because it looks like your posting to two different end points.